# simple alert view for connection check in a web view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

dear Stackover community,

Nearly a week I'm struggling around with the fact that I must have a connection check
for my web view so I'm surviving the App review process by Apple :-)

I know that I can use the Reachablity sample but for me as a beginner I would say its not smart to deal with such a code.

I found out that it gets a bit simpler with a simple alert and code like this:

```
    -(void)webview:(UIWebView *)webview didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                message:@"Can't connect. Please check your internet Connection"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show]; }
```

My problem is that I implemented this code into the .m of my Webviewcontroller and connected the delegate to the Filesowner but the App won't be that nice to me to show me the error message :-)

At the moment I'm using Xcode 4.2.1 with ARC enabled and storyboards.

Would anybody please give me a step by step guide how to get this work?
Its probably the last code I need for my App.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The delegate method is:

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Note it's "`-(void)webView`" not "`-(void)webview`". Just capitalize the "v" in "view" and it will work.

To answer your subsequent question:"now when i stop the loading of the page the error message comes too. Is there another tip ?"

As you can see an `NSError` is passed to your function. That error contains information about the failure. You can see that information by adding: `NSLog(@"Epic fail with error:%@",error);` ('Epic' added for dramatic effect). When you log that error you will see a `code` 'property' listed. Through some experimentation you will see that this code property changes based on the type of error. It seems that this code will equal `-1009` for a connection error. All of the possible [errors are enumerated here under "URL Loading System Error Codes"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html). Best of all since they are defined in an enumeration you don't have to remember much of that. You can just use:

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webview didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error.code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet){
        NSLog(@"You are not connected");
    }
}
```

Comment: oh damn I'm really stupid at all :-) thanks you rescued my life !

Comment: @0815jogger Don't feel bad we've all done it before. If this answer solved the problem please accept it.

Comment: It solved my problem but how it is in life . You solved one and gets thousand new ones :-) now when i stop the loading of the page the error message comes too. Is there another tip ?

Comment: @0815jogger Edited answer in response to subsequent question.

Comment: Thanks to your subsequent answer and help too. OK I found out that I get the error -999 NSURLErrorCancelled so I want to say the program that it haven't show the alert when this kind of error happens. Am I right? so I try to find out how its done by your if code you've given me. Thanks in advance

Comment: OK I'm using this kind of code and it worked magically :-) I'm really happy quiet now!!!!!!      if([error code] == NSURLErrorCancelled) return; // Ignore this error

Answer (score 0):

TRY ...
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:[error localizedString
]
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

Comment: What happens if I will write : message:[error localizedString] ?